# Meaning of RecognitionMode parameter in Azure Speech Service's (Javascript) startContinuousRecognitionAsync()

Tags: javascript, speech-to-text, azure-cognitive-services

The Javascript SDK for the MS Azure Speech Service shows the SpeechRecognizer class having a startContinuousRecognitionAsync() method overload taking a RecognitionMode parameter. The equivalent calls in all the other language SDKs don't appear to allow for such a parameter.

RecognitionMode is an enum with three values: "Interactive", "Conversation" and "Dictation".

What is the different effect of using each of these - especially the first two?